# Optimization of the google dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using the dataproc cluster for spark processing. I am new to whole google cloud stuff. In our application we have 100s of jobs which uses dataproc. With every job we spawn new cluster and terminate it once the job is over. I am using pyspark for processing purpose.

1. Is it safe to use hybrid of stable node and pre-emptible nodes for the cost reduction?
2. What is the best software configuration for improving the performance of the dataproc cluser. I am aware of the in-house infrastructure optimisation of hadoop/spark cluster. Is it applicable as it is for dataroc cluster or something else is needed?
3. Which instance type is best suit for dataproc cluster when we are processing avro formatted data around 150GB of size.
4. I have tried spark's dataframe caching / persist for time optimization. But it was not that useful. Is there any way to instruct spark that entire resources (memory, processing power) belong to this job so that it can process it faster?
5. Does reading and writing back to GCS bucket have a performance hit? If yes, is there any way to optimize it?

Any help in time and price optimisation is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Manish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to use hybrid of stable node and pre-emptible nodes for the cost reduction?

That's absolutely fine. We've used that on 300+ node clusters, only issues were with long-running clusters when nodes were getting preempted, and jobs were not optimised to account for node reclamation (no RDD replication, huge long-running DAGs). Also Tez does not like preemptible nodes getting reclaimed.

> Is it applicable as it is for dataroc cluster or something else is needed?

Correct. However Google Storage driver has different characteristics when it comes to operation latency (for example, FileOutputCommitter can take huge amounts of time when trying to do recursive move or remove with overpartitioned output), and memory usage (writer buffers are 64 Mb vs 4 Kb on HDFS).

> Which instance type is best suit for dataproc cluster when we are processing avro formatted data around 150GB of size.

Only performance tests can help with that.

> I have tried spark's dataframe caching / persist for time optimization. But it was not that useful. Is there any way to instruct spark that entire resources (memory, processing power) belong to this job so that it can process it faster?

Make sure to use dynamic allocation and your cluster is sized to your workload. Scheduling tab in YARN UI should show utilisation close to 100% (if not, your cluster is oversized to the job, or you have not enough partitions). In Spark UI, better to have number running tasks close to number of cores (if not, it again might be not enough partitions, or cluster is oversized).

> Does reading and writing back to GCS bucket have a performance hit? If yes, is there any way to optimize it?

From throughput perspective, GCS is not bad, but it is much worse in case of many small files, both from reading (when computing splits) and writing (when FileOutputCommitter) perspective. Also many parallel writes can result in OOMs due to bigger write buffer size.

Comment: Question regarding suggested 100% CPU utilisation. There are few constraints that make it hardly reachable, first - some of our tasks consume a lot of RAM, hence executor memory is relatively high (20GB), second - extended memory instances are expensive and don't have sustained usage discounts. Do you have any suggestions?